# rails run specific migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I've deleted a table in the database, call it X.  db:migrate no longer works.  I have a migration file called CreateX.  Is there a way to run just that specific migration?

Comment: The question is a duplicate.  The answer here is better.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version
```

Or you can go up or down from a specific version:

```
db:migrate:up VERSION=my_version
db:migrate:down VERSION=my_version
```

Comment: rake db:migrate:redo seems to work for me (db:specific:redo just gives an error, I'm imagining a version issue)

Comment: Oops yah, you were right, that was my custom rake task mixed in, but I fixed it those should work well now.

Comment: N.B. If the table has been dropped from the database, `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=my_version` may do _nothing_, because the schema_migrations table still says it is done. In the same situation `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version` may _fail_ because it cannot drop the table. In this case, comment out the `down` method in the migration temporarily and re-run `rake db:migrate:redo...`