# no such file to load -- pg unable to run migrations manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, linode

I am using pg for dev and test in local machine only

its in dev and test group out in gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

rails version is

Rails 3.0.19
ruby 1.8.7

I used moonshine or shorter cut of capistrano

```
capistrano:deploy
```

the migrations file can't be migrated using capistrano, throws an error.

I am trying to run migrations manually inside server

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate VERSION=20140205173759_add_hebrew_to_piles.rb
```

I have three files and wanted to run rake migrate on each one (got it from stackoverlow, [rails run specific migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316889/rails-run-specific-migration))

and got

```
no such file to load -- pg
```

I am using mysql as production database so I don't understand why is looking for pg inside my server? any help?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to run one kind of database locally and another kind in production. This is a great example of why. You should consider running mysql locally or postgres on production to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: @tyler I understand but the mysql production db has already been created, and I am more familiar with pg so I tested it locally any way you can just add  RAILS_ENV=production when you run the rake db:migrate

Comment: If you're stuck running mysql in production, you might consider learning and developing with mysql as a best practice.  As for "you can just add RAILS_ENV=production when you run the rake db:migrate": if it was that straightforward and problem-free, you wouldn't have to ask the question above, would you?